# Why the 040000 mean directory in Git?

Tags: git

We know the `100644` means a file with permission `644` in git, but why the `040000` means a directory?

if the `040` mean a directory, what's the `000` mean?

Comment: Can you add some more information — like which git command did you run, and exactly what was the output?

Comment: See the the duplicate, and read both answers.